# Read data from MongoDB (gridfs) via Matlab and Java driver

Tags: java, matlab, mongodb, gridfs

I am working with Matlab and the Java driver. After writing some big data to the DB I want to read them out later.
The files are about 100MB big and because of that I am writing them into GridFS.

I read the data with the Java driver into Matlab this way:

```
dbgridfs = GridFS(db, 'data_gridfs');
file1 = dbgridfs.findOne('bigdata');
```

After that code I will get an object in my Matlab workspace:
Name       Size            Bytes  Class
file1      1x1             com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile

Now I have a problem with converting the (Java?)-object into a nativ Matlab variable.

I searched a lot on different sites, but I don't get it. At the moment I am writing the data on my harddisk and after that I read it into a native Matlab variable - but this is a really dirty way and don't ask me relating to the performance :(

Are there any existing solutions I missed with the Java driver and/or do you know some code which could help me?
Thanks for your help.

regards
matl

Comment: Has anybody an idea how I could solve the problem. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask me.

Comment: You probably will need to convert to the correct type and use the matlab java libraries. See: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-data-returned-from-a-java-method.html

Comment: I tried to convert the Java object to a native Matlab variable with:
    test = cell(file1)
but this returns me the string:
    test = [1x1 com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile]
and not the data. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Thats setting the `test` var with the string representation - you'll need to get the data and convert to the correct type.  You can get the inputStream of the file from: `file1.getInputStream()`.  This link might help you display the stream: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/39039

Comment: I do not get it.

I can probaly access different party of the object but I do not get the data out of it.

For example file1.get('filename') gives me ans = song_1 and of course that is correct.

Comment: Looking up the mothodes with:
methods(file1)

gives me this list:

Methods for class com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile:

GridFSDBFile         getClass             getMetaData          notifyAll            toMap                
containsField        getContentType       getUploadDate        numChunks            toString             
containsKey          getFilename          hashCode             put                  validate             
equals               getId                isPartialObject      putAll               wait

Comment: get                  getInputStream       keySet               removeField          writeTo              
getAliases           getLength            markAsPartialObject  save                 
getChunkSize         getMD5               notify               setMetaData          

Writing data to the harddisk is running well with: file1.writeTo('test')

But file1.getInputStream('song_1') gives me:
No method 'getInputStream' with matching signature found for class 'com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile'.

Answer (score 1):

I have never responded to any forum question, but I have benefitted a lot especially from stackoverflow, so I thought I have to give something back at least once. Since the above issue was bugging me now for nearly two days and I finally stitched together a solution I thought this would be a good topic to give something back to the community.

I had the same issue of retrieving an image (.png) from a MongoDB/GridFS with the Java driver. First, as also described above, you need to retrieve the file Java object:

```
    import com.mongodb.*;
    import com.mongodb.gridfs.*;

    mongoClient = MongoClient('server_name',27017);
    db = mongoClient.getDB('database_name');
    imgData = GridFS(db,'image_data');
```

The above code part is getting the collection with the image data. Afterwards, the image data Java object can be retrieved:

```
    javaIObj = imgData.findOne('image_name.png');
```

Now ByteArrayOutputStream is needed where the data stream can be piped into instead of a file:

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

    baos = ByteArrayOutputStream();
    javaIObj.writeTo(baos);
```

The output stream needs again to be piped into a ByteArrayInputStream which can be used to construct an ImageIO object:

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;    

    bais = ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    jbi = ImageIO.read(bais);
```

Now the actual Matlab image as matrix can be retrieved and displayed:

```
    nrows = jbi.getHeight; ncols = jbi.getWidth;
    data = jbi.getData.getPixels(0,0,ncols,nrows,[]);
    matImg = reshape(data,ncols,nrows)';

    imagesc(matImg);
```

I do not know if this is the perfect solution, but it worked for me.

Cheers!