# Storing images on MongoDB with GridFS using MATLAB

Tags: java, mongodb, matlab, gridfs

I need to push images (>16MB) in MongoDB through GridFS using MATLAB connected with the Java driver.

I found a topic on how to get out Images from MongoDB with MATLAB there :
[Read data from MongoDB (gridfs) via Matlab and Java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198612/read-data-from-mongodb-gridfs-via-matlab-and-java-driver)

But Could not find how to push the image in the first time